# PostgreSql applying a Parallel Sequential Scan instead of Index Scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have indexes on all columns Juliet, Five, Juilet1 to Juliet15 even then PostgresSQL is doing a Parallel Seq Scan instead of an Index Scan. Why is this happening?

The PostgresSql query is,

```
SELECT juliet FROM romeo 
WHERE (((romeo.juliet1 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet2 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet3 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet4 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet5 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet6 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet7 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet8 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet9 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet10 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet11 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet12 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet13 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet14 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.juliet15 IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732') 
   OR romeo.five IN ('S66.303S', 'S66303S', 'S52.009S', 'S52009S', 'S32.466G', 'S32466G', 'H44.139', 'H44139', 'H35.732', 'H35732'))));
```

This is the query plan generated by explain analyze. As you can see that a Parallel Seq Scan is being applied on Romeo.

```
Gather  (cost=1000.000..2459531.510 rows=14964 width=9) (actual time=734.439..11268.059 rows=376 loops=1)
    Workers Planned: 2
    Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on romeo  (cost=0.000..2457035.110 rows=6235 width=9) (actual time=741.013..11256.264 rows=125 loops=3)
          Filter: (((juliet1)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet2)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet3)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet4)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet5)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet6)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet7)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet8)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet9)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet10)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet11)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet12)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet13)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet14)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((juliet15)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])) OR ((five)::text = ANY ('three'::text[])))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 4774850
Planning time: 0.533 ms
Execution time: 60030.289 ms
```

Index statements for all the indexes on the table.

```
CREATE INDEX juliet1_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet1);
CREATE INDEX juliet2_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet2);
CREATE INDEX juliet3_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet3);
CREATE INDEX juliet4_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet4);
CREATE INDEX juliet5_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet5);
CREATE INDEX juliet6_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet6);
CREATE INDEX juliet7_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet7);
CREATE INDEX juliet8_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet8);
CREATE INDEX juliet9_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet9);
CREATE INDEX juliet10_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet10);
CREATE INDEX juliet11_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet11);
CREATE INDEX juliet12_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet12);
CREATE INDEX juliet13_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet13);
CREATE INDEX juliet14_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet14);
CREATE INDEX juliet15_idx_pd_activity ON pd_activity (juliet15);
```

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE INDEX` statements for the indexes on the table?

Comment: How many other columns are there in the table?

Comment: How does this not blow up? `'three'::text[]`

Comment: The query in the question seems to be different than the query used for generating the execution plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there are 42 more columns in the table, and the query is the same that is used to generate plan.

Comment: The plan shows the condition `(((juliet1)::text = ANY ('three'::text[]))` which translates to `juliet1 in ('three')` - that's not the condition shown in your query

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added the index statements, please give them a look.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is just how the plan represents, I guess.

Comment: Sry, my mistake missed index on the column five. It executed inside 4seconds after adding index on column Five. thanks.

Comment: Do you always include all those (de-normalized) columns with the same IN list in the WHERE clause?

Comment: It uses the plan it thinks will be faster.  Maybe its estimate is correct, maybe it isn't.  You can `set max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0` to force it not to use parallel, or `set enable_seqscan=off` to force it to use index scans when possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yup there are many such use cases.